# SML Callin a function from a datatype

Tags: sml

I'm learning sml and I got stuck in an excercise. They gave me a datatype made like this

```
datatype Expr =  X
                |Y
                | Avg of Expr * Expr
                | Mul of Expr * Expr
```

and i need to write a function called compute so i can do the average or the multiply operation where the type of the function is

```
Expr -> int -> int -> int
```

so I made this

```
val rec compute =   fn X => (fn x => fn y => x)
                | Y => (fn x => fn y => y)
                | Avg(e1,e2) => ( fn x => fn y => ((compute e1 x y) + (compute e2 x y)) div 2)
                | Mul(e1,e2) => ( fn x => fn y => (compute e1 x y ) * (compute e2 x y))
```

Now I need to call it from terminal but I don't know how to call the function.. I tried with

```
compute Avg 4 2;
```

but it gives me

```
    poly: : error: Type error in function application.
   Function: compute : Expr -> int -> int -> int
   Argument: Avg : Expr * Expr -> Expr
   Reason: Can't unify Expr to Expr * Expr -> Expr (Incompatible types)
Found near compute Avg 4 2
Static Errors
```

Can someone guide me through this? Thanks to all
P.S. Is there a way to made this with fun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Avg` is not a value of the type `Expr`, it's a constructor that creates an `Expr` from a pair of `Expr`s.
This is also indicated by your compiler in the error message:

```
Avg : Expr * Expr -> Expr
```

You should use it like this:

```
compute (Avg(Y,X)) 4 2
```

which makes 3.

Your function is already correct, but using `fun` makes it more readable:

```
fun compute X x y = x
  | compute Y x y = y
  | compute (Avg (e1, e2)) x y = ((compute e1 x y) + (compute e2 x y)) div 2
  | compute (Mul (e1, e2)) x y = (compute e1 x y) * (compute e2 x y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the function is:

```
fun compute e x y =
    case e of
        X => x
      | Y => y
      | Avg (e1, e2) => (compute e1 x y + compute e2 x y) div 2
      | Mul (e1, e2) => compute e1 x y * compute e2 x y
```